# pass parameters to after-feature karate

Tags: karate

I discovered after-feature in karate which is very useful. But I didn't find how to pass parameters to after-feature from main feature. Ex: access token to delete a user account or a user_id.
Here is call of after-feature.feature in my main feature:

```
* configure afterFeature = function(){ karate.call('classpath: AfterFeature.feature'); }
```

Here is my AfterFeature.feature

```
Scenario:
    * url 'XXX'
    * path 'YYY'
    * param foo = bar which should come from main feature
    * header Authorization = 'Bearer ' + accessToken which should come from main feature
    * method delete
    * status 204
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`karate.call()` can take parameters.

```
karate.call('classpath: AfterFeature.feature', { some: 'value' });
```

Comment: Thanks @Peter Thomas. I tried `* configure afterFeature = function(){ karate.call('classpath: AfterFeature.feature', { accessToken: xxxx }); }`. My after feature is run correctly, it works, but I don't understand why: I don't send `foo` parameter from main feature. How the AfterFeature.feature knows bar value for foo parameter?